# Using MS SQL/Oracle's XML datatype in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Is this possible? Situation is that I want to store some XML in my database, but keep it as generic as possible in case we need to deploy it to a difference backend.

I realise I could store it as a String, but I believe MSSQL/Oracle optimise and validate XML if you store it this way, and let you search on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide an implementation of org.hibernate.usertype.UserType you can provide logic for mapping an arbitrary Java type to one or more database columns.

- http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html

You can view a few examples of UserTypes here:

- http://www.hibernate.org/288.html
- http://www.hibernate.org/169.html
- http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/User+Types+in+Hibernate
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jhook/archive/2005/12/handling_type_c.html

Or just Google "hibernate usertype" and find many more. :)

Comment: Do you know of any library implementations of XML which would prevent the need of rolling our own implementation?